# how to structure an asp.net app to have language in the address bar?

Tags: url-routing, webforms

I want to have all addresses in my asp.net(web forms) application contain the selected language to allow search engines to index both language content. So I want it to be something like www.mysite.com/en/items/35
So what should I do to have it like that, I don't want to create page version for each of my language. I can set the page routing but how then I will understand what language to show in my page? should I analyse the address string and search for "/en/", "/ee/" and etc???

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a [rewriting engine](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) so that the url

```
www.mysite.com/en/items/35
```

Is rewritten to:

```
www.mysite.com/items.aspx?lang=en&id=35
```

Then you simply write some code to look at the query string.